# PHP 0mq sink not receiving messages

Tags: php, zeromq

I've implemented the 0mq ventilator/worker/sink example in PHP.  The ventilator sends messages to the workers.  The workers receive these messages and send the results to the sink.

The workers are correctly receiving the messages, but the sink never receives their responses.  What am I doing wrong?

Using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 and libzmq v2.2.0 inside a Virtualbox VM.

Ventilator:

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
$sender = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$sender->bind('tcp://*:5557');
echo 'Sending IDs to workers...', PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++) {
    $sender->send($i);
}
```

Worker:

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
$receiver = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$receiver->connect('tcp://localhost:5557');
$sender = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$sender->connect('tcp://localhost:5558');
while (true) {
    $i = $receiver->recv();
    echo 'Processing ', $i, PHP_EOL;
    $sender->send($i * 2);
}
```

Sink:

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
$receiver = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$receiver->connect('tcp://*:5558');
echo 'Receiving rows from workers...', PHP_EOL;
while (true) {
    $result = $receiver->recv();
    echo $result, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

Workers say 'Processing 0 - 99...' but sink shows no output.

Expected:

Sink outputs 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Silly error.  The sink should have used bind() instead of connect().  Resolved.